# Gigya Android not going into Pending Registration callback on Login

Tags: android, gigya

I'm trying to use the Gigya callback for `onPendingRegistration` because our registration requires additional details when a user logs in with social media. The initial social registration works fine because I can verify that the user exists in the Gigya console but the registration for our specific app doesn't push through because of the pending registration status.

Currently my login function has the callbacks for `onSuccess`, `onError`, and `onPendingRegistration`. For some reason it always goes into the `onError` callback but when checking the logs, it says that the error is 206001 which is "Account Pending Registration"

**Login Function**

```
public void facebookLoginTapped(View view) {
    processGigyaLogin(FACEBOOK);
}

private void processGigyaLogin(String loginProvider) {
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("screenSet","GIGYA-RegistrationLogin");
    params.put("startScreen","gigya-complete-registration-screen");
    mGigya.login(loginProvider, new HashMap<>(), new GigyaLoginCallback<MyAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(MyAccount obj) {
            // Success
            Log.i("GIGYA-CDC", obj.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(GigyaError error) {
            // Fail
            Log.e("GIGYA-CDC", error.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPendingRegistration(@NonNull GigyaApiResponse response, @NonNull IPendingRegistrationResolver resolver) {
            Log.d("GIGYA-CDC", "onPendingRegistration");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I found the cause. I didnt notice it on the documentation but pending registrations are not yet supported by the v4 sdk

Comment: When overriding the "onPendingRegistration" callback you are not directed to the callback?

Comment: @TalMihr yes it doesn't.. it goes into the `onError` callback rather than `onPendingRegistration`

Comment: Remove the super call. When overriding an interruption don't call the super. The Interruption callbacks were designed to direct you to the onError if you do not override them. When you do u must not call the super.

Comment: Yes I did that but it still doesnt go in.. I left the code block with a simple Log call just to see if it goes in but instead it goes into the onError callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. You need to make sure that the native app part is working for interruptions to work. So for the past few weeks I had to work with setting up the social logins without using the native SDKs as they were still being setup by a different team. Anyway long story short, once I started wiring up the native SDK with the app (ie using the Facebook or Google app to do the authentication), then the `@Override` methods in the SDK v4 documentation starts to work.

As earlier noted by TalMihr, you shouldn't be using `screen-sets` with the interruptions and work with the `resolver` interfaces. I'm working on that right now and I'll update my answer once I get the actual resolver object to work.

FYI: My current setup to make this work(using Gigya SDK v 4.0.1):

```
//Facebook
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.41.0'

//Google Sign In
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

Everything else is similar to the sample app in terms of code.

**Edit:**

It works! I haven't used the `resolver` interface to work this out btw. I was told to try and make screen-sets work as we wanted to avoid creating additional UI. How it works is you'd need to provide additional parameters when you use the screen-set.

**Pending Registration Code:**

```
private void processGigyaLogin(String loginProvider) {
    mGigya = Gigya.getInstance(MyAccount.class);

    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("screenSet","SCREEN-SET-RegistrationLogin");
    params.put("startScreen","gigya-complete-registration-screen");

    mGigya.login(loginProvider, new HashMap<>(), new GigyaLoginCallback<MyAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(MyAccount obj) {
            // Success
            Log.i("GIGYA-CDC", "Logged in using" + obj.getSocialProviders() + " as: " + obj.getProfile().getFirstName() + " " + obj.getProfile().getLastName() + ", " + obj.getProfile().getEmail());
        }

        @Override
        public void onConflictingAccounts(@NonNull GigyaApiResponse response, @NonNull ILinkAccountsResolver resolver) {
            Log.d("GIGYA-CDC", "onConflictingAccounts");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPendingRegistration(@NonNull GigyaApiResponse response, @NonNull IPendingRegistrationResolver resolver) {
            Log.d("GIGYA-CDC", "onPendingRegistration");
            params.put("regToken", response.getField("regToken", String.class));
            mGigya.showScreenSet("SCREEN-SET-RegistrationLogin", false, params, new GigyaPluginCallback<MyAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onLogin(@NonNull MyAccount obj) {
                    Log.i("GIGYA-CDC", "Logged in using" + obj.getSocialProviders() + " as: " + obj.getProfile().getFirstName() + " " + obj.getProfile().getLastName() + ", " + obj.getProfile().getEmail());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(GigyaError error) {
            Log.e("GIGYA-CDC", error.getLocalizedMessage() + " Status Code: " + error.getStatusCode() + " Error Code: " + error.getErrorCode());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When overriding the "onPendingRegistration" callback you are provided with an instance of the "IPendingRegistrationResolver" which can help you resolve this interruption.
Use it to set the relevant additional fields you require for the sign in process.

If you are using business apis such as the "mGigya.login(...)" calls, resolving the interruptions is your responsibility. The resolver pattern provided is used just for that. **This method does not use the screensets feature.**

See:
https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android+SDK+v4#AndroidSDKv4-HandlingInterruptions
For more info on the interruption handing pattern.

Comment: Yes this is what I want to accomplish if it were possible without screen-sets however  the callback for `onPendingRegistration` is not being triggered.. according to Android docs it isnt currently supported (it isn't explicitly written but if you check the docs, GigyaSwift supports it but Android doesn't. This is true for version 4.0.0 atm

Comment: onPendingRegistration is supported with the version 4.0.0. It is working for me exactly as it should. When overriding the "onPendingRegistration" I just remove the super.onPendingRegistration call from the callback body and it is being triggered

Comment: hmmm...weird ok lemme try I hope it does work, it'll solve a lot of problems if it does

Comment: Double checked it on my end. I'll continue to monitor it

Comment: So I just checked on it, apologies if it took awhile I had to setup my personal pc to run the project. I removed `super.onPendingRegistration` and it didn't go inside. instead I got "error_description=206001 - Account Pending Registration" from the `onResult` inside my logcat.

Comment: Can u post the code snippet u are using ill check it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196583/discussion-between-talmihr-and-kobowo).

Comment: I edited my question to show how the code is being used, also I opened the chat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using screen-sets, which it seems you are, you will just need to add whatever fields you require into the Registration Completion screen, then when a social user logs in or registers, they will automatically be prompted with the Registration Completion screen to complete any missing data.

If, for some reason, you are collecting extra data explicitly from social users that you do *not* collect from other users, then you will need to customize the registration completion screen using 'Visible When' flags and you will need to check what provider the user registered through, and attach a JS check to the 'visible when' and add a "close if complete" option to the screen, so it will be bypassed if the user is not coming from social.

Something else to check, based upon your error, be sure that the mobile screen-set registration completion screen contains all *Required* schema fields, (i.e., Consents) or the users will not be able to complete registration.

ref: https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Screen-Sets#Screen-Sets-RegistrationFlow

Comment: The fields are found on the screen-set already. My problem is getting to the registration complete page but I think I might not be implementing screen-sets properly yet. I tried using the showScreenSet method but it returned the same error.

Comment: @kobowo Assuming you haven't changed any of the screen-set behavior, the registration completion screen should be firing automatically when needed, there is nothing you need to do to make it happen, other than have the necessary fields included. I added a quick page here: https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Configuring+A+Registration+Completion+Screen . Maybe it will help. If all else fails, I suggest creating a NEW screen-set collection and starting over from the beginning. https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/UI+Builder#UIBuilder-AddingNewScreen-SetCollections

Comment: I'll check on that but I don't think it was changed. I didn't make the screen-sets that the app is using (however I did check on the set I am calling and it appears the IDs for the pages are the default name). I'm just on the consuming side since I need to implement the mobile version of the website. I followed the documentation on the Android SDK docs and called the `showScreenSet` method passing the LoginRegistration screen-set...so just to clarify...assuming the behavior of the screen-sets weren't changed, would I get into pending registration screen?

Comment: So I tried using `showScreenSet` without any parameters (I passed in an empty HashMap) and I tried logging in with one of our social logins and the logs returned this to me: Navigation is blocked: <redacted>&error=pending_registration&error_description=206001+-+Account+Pending+Registration